# VB Visual Studio 2017: Error Managed Debugging Assistant 'DisconnectedContext'

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I got the "Managed Debugging Assistant 'DisconnectedContext' " error.

> Managed Debugging Assistant 'DisconnectedContext' 
>     Message=Managed Debugging Assistant 'DisconnectedContext' : 'Transition into COM context 0xfc94b0 for this RuntimeCallableWrapper failed with the following error: System call failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010100 (RPC_E_SYS_CALL_FAILED)). This is typically because the COM context 0xfc94b0 where this RuntimeCallableWrapper was created has been disconnected or it is busy doing something else. Releasing the interfaces from the current COM context (COM context 0xfc9568). This may cause corruption or data loss. To avoid this problem, please ensure that all COM contexts/apartments/threads stay alive and are available for context transition, until the application is completely done with the RuntimeCallableWrappers that represents COM components that live inside them.
>   Blockquote

The program is reading and analyzing about 200 large excel files, generating one output large excel file. So far I was using it on a smaller amount of files, so perhaps it has to do something with larger memory usage. On the other hand the machines I use have 16GB of RAM. While n run time it doesn't look like memory leak. I don't use pointers, or dynamic memory allocations - simply open files, read, write and close.

While I read I can disable the "'DisconnectedContext' " I prefer to understand how to locate the problem and fix it.

The problem occurs on two separated machines.

How can I debug it?

Where to start?

Thank you

Comment: Does the error occur when reading or when writing Excel? What are you using for the reading and writing, e.g. EPPLus or something else?

Comment: It occurs during the read phase. Many files and many lines to read.I use "Microsoft.Office.Interop".

Comment: i use VS 2017, writing in Visual Basic. The problem occurec on VS 2019 as well.

Comment: Use Task Manager, Processes tab and check how many Excel.exe processes are running at the time the error occurs.  It should be one, but if you see hundreds then 16GB isn't going to help.  Use only one instance of Application.

Comment: Hi Hans. I checked and there is only one. The memory usage is less constantly ~40% , with very small increase over time.

Comment: Another strange thing which I am not sure is related: The form I use to control the program increase many textboxes I use to indicate the progress (how many lines were read etc.), The progress is not as I would expect. It looks like it takes a lot of time since the program writes the data to the box until it appears, Another thing: I can see the form in run time, but not to control it. for example, I can't even move it on screen until the whole program is finished.

Comment: @YigalB (1) You may well find that a third-party library, such as [EPPLus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/) (watch out which license you want), works better as it is unencumbered by a GUI. (2) Using a [BackgroundWorker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker) in conjunction with a third-party library would leave the form responsive.

Comment: Thanks, but I prefer to use the free non licenses built in solution.

Comment: @YigalB It would have been an easy, zero-cost solution. Have you tried pausing the code between each file? (Perhaps with `Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)`.) It could be that Excel needs some time, perhaps a second or two, to clean up.

Comment: @Andrew Morton : nice idea. No - I didn't try that. I will give it a try. On the other hand: is there a way for me to check if the file closure has finished correctly? this way I will not have to guess the number of seconds required for the sleep.

Comment: @YigalB I have no idea. It might be that you can process perhaps 24 without a break, and then give it maybe a 5 second break to catch up. You'll have to experiment (and it might not work like that anyway).